# She danced better than any of us (did?)

Tags: ellipsis, exam-questions, comparative-constructions, grammar-myths

I read this sentence :

> The three individuals are so different that their tastes vary from one another's.

In this *their tastes* are compared so apostrophe is used with *another*

But in this sentence

> She was not a good singer but she danced better than any of us.

Why *did* or something like that has not been used ? Like previous sentence in which *their tastes* is compared here *their dance* is being compared.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key here is that the first sentence uses "taste" as a possessive noun. The word another can be used as another's in the possessive form, which is known as a fused head construction [1].  Example:

> These two imparadised in one **another's** arms.

The second sentence uses dance as a verb and not a noun, which means the same rules do not apply here. However, you can get close to the first sentence by using dance as a possessive noun, such as :

> She was not a good singer, but her dance was better than any of ours.

Or

> She was not a good singer, but none of our dance was as good as her's.

[1] https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/another

Helpful read : http://www.grammar.com/fused-participle-noun-or-pronoun-and-%E2%80%91ing-phrase/